# Adding existing records to has_many :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I'm building a dictionary application where I have some concepts linked to some words using a join model. I have a form to edit each concept, where I can edit its words, add new words to it or associate existing words with it.

I'm using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `update_attributes`, but this only works with the already associated words or the newly created ones. For the existing words that weren't previously associated, I get errors like this `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Word with ID=4 for Concept with ID=1000)` when ActiveRecord runs a select on the join model.

Here are my models:

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :notes, :text, :grammar_tag_list

  has_many :semantic_relations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :concepts, :through => :semantic_relations
end

class Concept < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :meaning_tag_list, :words_attributes

  has_many :semantic_relations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :words, :through=> :semantic_relations, :order => 'knowledge_id ASC'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :words, :reject_if => lambda { |w| w[:text].blank? }
end

class SemanticRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :word, :inverse_of => :semantic_relations
  belongs_to :concept, :inverse_of => :semantic_relations
end
```

I have managed it to work using the following method in my Concepts controller (calling it before `update_attributes`), but it seems a quite dirty approach. Isn't there any proper way to achieve this?

```
def check_words
  current_ids = @concept.word_ids
  new_ids = params[:concept][:words_attributes].map do |w|
    id = w[1][:id].to_i
    unless id == 0
      unless current_ids.include? id
        id
      end
    end
  end
  @concept.word_ids = current_ids + new_ids unless new_ids.blank?
end
```